# Linux起動時のシステムの動作イメージ

Tags: linux

```
ide_setup:hdc=ide-scsi
Ide0:BM-DMA at 0xff00-0xff07,BIOS settings;hdaDMA,hdb:DMA
```

の動作イメージを教えていただけますでしょうか？
このログが何を表しているかを教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

断片すぎてなにがいいたい/ききたいのかわかりませんが

IBM PC-AT 互換機のうち DMA 対応のものは `IDE` ハードディスクを読み書きするインターフェイスにおいてバスマスター DMA が使えて、その制御のための I/O アドレスとして `0xFF00-0xFF07` を用いるハードウエア仕様です。専門用語の羅列となりましたが、意味が分からなければ気にする必要はありません。

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Technology_Attachment

- BM は Bus-Master
- DMA は Direct Memory Access
- at 0xff00-0xff07 は I/O アドレス
- BIOS settings は BIOS の設定値から先のアドレスを読んだ
- `/dev/hda` も `/dev/hdb` も DMA アクセスできる

程度の意味しかないです（つまり知っている人には当たり前すぎてほぼ無意味なレベルのログ）